# How to stop angular ng build --prod

Tags: node.js, angular

Hi I am using nodejs and angularjs to construct a web application. I deployed the app to aws ec2, I used pm2 start app.js to start nodejs and ng build --prod to start angularjs. I can stop nodejs by pm2 stop, but how can i stop angularJS. if I don't stop angularjs and start another nodejs server, how can the angular js know which node server to send the requests?

Comment: You don't stop the ng build --prod. This command only builds a bundle that you need to serve using some web server like apache or nginx. It's not a daemon.

Comment: AngularJS !== Angular. Based on the `ng` command I'm assuming you're using Angular.

Comment: @EliasSoares so how do we clean it, can we delete all the file in dist folder?